# Forward files Post from one rest API to another rest api

Tags: java, spring-boot

Can someone help me to understand how to send files Post from one rest API to another rest API

Comment: Please follow this link
Focus on the Junit file which is uploading file to rest API - So same you neet to do from your first API implementation
https://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/resteasy/using-rest-services-to-manage-download-and-upload-of-files/

It is just a HTTP call with multipart type of request body -  How you send JSON or anything else from one API to another same way you sed the file with its right type.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `OKHttpClient` class in your src post method:

```
public static boolean uploadFile(String actionUrl,File file,String token) {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
            .build();
    MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data");
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, file);
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(actionUrl)
            .method("POST", body)
            .addHeader("Authorization", token)
            .addHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose")
            .addHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")
            .build();
    try {
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of your first REST API from which you would want to invoke a request to the second one as a client. The fact that it is also a REST API by itself is irrelevant. So, you can use any third-party Http client to send a request to your second REST API. Here Here are some popular Http clients

1. [Apache Http client](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.2.x/)
2. [OK Http client](https://square.github.io/okhttp/)
3. There is an Open source MgntUtils (written and maintained by me). It has a simplistic Http client as well. It doesn't give all the wealth of features as the other 2 above but is a very simple in use. You can try that one as well. Here is a [HttpClient Javadoc](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/lifecycle/management/httpclient/HttpClient.html). The MgntUtils library can be obtained as a [maven artifact](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) or from [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) (with source code and Javadoc)